# Cannot set process title in a PHP command line script using cli_set_process_title() OS X?

Tags: php, process, command-line-interface

I am trying to build a simple daemon script with PHP and I would like to set the process title to see it in `ps` and `top` output. This code is:

```
#!/usr/bin/php
<?php
// Daemonize
cli_set_process_title('daemonized');
$pid = pcntl_fork(); // parent gets the child PID, child gets 0
if($pid){ // 0 is false in PHP
    // Only the parent will know the PID. Kids aren't self-aware
    // Parent says goodbye!
    print "Parent : " . getmypid() . " exiting\n";
    exit();
}
print "Child : " . getmypid() . "\n";
    while (true) {
        // daemon stuff...
        sleep(2);
    }
```

But I cannot set the title, when I launch the script I get the following warning:

```
$ ./daemonize.php
PHP Warning:  cli_set_process_title(): cli_set_process_title had an error: Not initialized correctly in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/daemonize.php on line 3

Warning: cli_set_process_title(): cli_set_process_title had an error: Not initialized correctly in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/daemonize.php on line 3
```

Where is the issue, what should I do in order to make it work?

Thanks for the attention!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is not really an answer, *per se*, but I am not sure that you can still do this with cli-php in OS X 10.10.x without running the process as the superuser or other not-so-secure hacks.

I have tried `chmod`ing the process (or more exactly the file that is being executed via `php file.php`), `chown`ing the GID to another group and also running the script using `sudo`. All of these options failed for me even though the php process was being run by an authorized user who belonged to the admin group.

My guess: Apple must be blocking this functionality for security reasons... and I suppose I can imagine why.

In the end, because I was targeting a Linux runtime, I refactored my code so that `cli_set_process_title()` was not mission critical and ran the command with the error suppression operator, `@cli_set_proc_title()` and just logged the fact that the command failed.

I would welcome more complete answers or other secure work arounds but after much wasted time this was the best I could come up with and I was unable to find any other answers.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for sharing your efforts, I have tried with sudo too, didn't worked, and it doesn't worth it as you said, it is not mission critical and I really can go without it, anyway, a safe work around would still be appreciated!

Comment: Would like to add that, even when running as root, a forked process still cannot set it's own process title. Only a group parent can do so.